# Exception thrown while executing UI block: [NSNull doubleValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x204329c00

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-native-svg, nsnull

I am trying to display icon relative to specific coordinates on a map, but I keep getting this error thrown, followed by:

```
removedChildren count(0) was not what we expected (1)
```

This won't allow the pin to show up on the map. Below is my code:

```
const [restaurant_Latitude, setRestaurantLatitude] = useState(0)
const [restaurant_Longitude, setRestaurantLongitude] = useState(0)
const [restaurantPositionError, setRestaurantPositionError] = useState(null)
```

Using react-native-svg to create an icon

```
const restaurantIcon = () =>{
      return(
        <Svg
          height = {30}
          width = {30}
        >
          <Ellipse
            cx="10"
            cy="10"
            rx="10"
            ry="10"
            fill="red"
            stroke="#fff"
            strokeWidth="2"
          />

        </Svg>
        )
    }
```

//useEffect to get restaurant's coordinates

```
useEffect(() =>{

...

displayRestaurantInfo = async () =>{
 let restaurantInfo = client_instance.getFoodInfo()

   setRestaurantLatitude(restaurantInfo.latitude)
   setRestaurantLongitude(restaurantInfo.longitude)
   setRestaurantPositionError(null)
}

displayRestaurantInfo()

)
}
```

...

//How it renders in the MapView

```
return(
      
        <MapView>

            <Marker 
                coordinate={ 
                    {latitude: restaurantLatitude,
                     longitude: restaurantLongitude,
                     error: position_error,
                    }}
              >
                <View>
                  {(restaurantIcon())}
                </View>
              </Marker>
</MapView>
```